# how can a website detect smartphone model?

Tags: javascript, php, detection, smartphone

How can a website detect the smartphone model of a device that requests a webpage?
Google Analytics can get that information as you can see in the image below:

[image]

I found this: http://blog.mobileesp.com/?p=177 but only a few phones are recognized by this script. I am looking for an PHP or Javascript solution

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/javascript-solution-to-detect-mobile-browser

Answer (score 0):

From Javascript you can read this property `navigator.userAgent` and PHP `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` both return you the browser version .

Comment: I am not looking for browser version, but for the mobile type. Like HTC One, HTC Windows Phone 8s et cetera. But thank you for your fast reply

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the best method for detecting mobile/tablet is to use the [PHP mobile_detect class](https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect) which is updated regularly as new devices are released. Unfortunately, I don't know if it provides a way to get the different device types.

User agent parsing is the method you'll have to use, and if mobile_detect doesn't have it, it ought to at least give you a good starting point on how it's done.

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look into that. Looks like what I am looking for ;)